# determine the number of intersecting records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of objects that have a variety of attributes:

| id | title | owner_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | The Name of the object | 5000 |
| 31 | Another name of a different object | 5000 |
| 71 | Yet another | 5000 |
| 19 | example title | 6000 |
| 21 | another example | 6000 |
| 23 | more example | 6000 |

and a list of attributes for each object (this list isn't completely normalized, but could be if necessary)

| object_id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | Blue |
| 25 | Green |
| 25 | Black |
| 31 | Blue |
| 31 | Purple |
| 71 | White |
| 19 | Grey |
| 19 | Blue |
| 21 | Yellow |
| 23 | Pink |
| 23 | Grey |

The goal is to calculate how many objects each owner has that overlap any attribtues with the other owners. So in the example, owner 5000 has 3 objects ( 25, 31, 71 ), and owner 6000 has 3 ( 19, 21, 23 ).

5000

- object 25 is (blue | green | black ) and overlaps with 19 because it also has a blue attribute.
- object 31 is (blue | purple | white ) and overlaps with 19 because it also has a blue attribute
- object 71 is (white) and doesn't overlap with any of owner 6000's objects, so it is unique.
  6000
- object 19 is (grey | blue) and overlaps 25
- object 21 is (yellow) and is unique
- object 23 is (pink & grey) is unique because none of 5000s objects are pink or grey

so since it doesn't really matter if 1 or all of the other owners objects match, i can create a summary table for each owner that lists out all of that companies unique attributes, which would look like:

5000: ( blue | green | black | purple | white )
6000: ( grey | blue | yellow | pink )

so the goal would be some output like:

| owner_a | owner_b | count_a | count_b | similarity_a_to_b | similarity_b_to_a | unique_a | unique_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 6000 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

the challenge is that I'm dealing with several thousand owner_ids, with several million objects, which have 10s of millions of attributes, so I'm trying to figure out how to summarize the data so I could generate these types of metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Well the SQL can be done via:

```
WITH objects (id, title, owner_id) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (25, 'The Name of the object', 5000),
      (31, 'Another name of a different object', 5000),
      (71, 'Yet another', 5000),
      (19, 'example title', 6000),
      (21, 'another example', 6000),
      (23, 'more example', 6000)
), attributes (object_id, attribute) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (25, 'Blue'),
      (25, 'Green'),
      (25, 'Black'),
      (31, 'Blue'),
      (31, 'Purple'),
      (71, 'White'),
      (19, 'Grey'),
      (19, 'Blue'),
      (21, 'Yellow'),
      (23, 'Pink'),
      (23, 'Grey')
), obj_att AS (
    SELECT o.*, a.*
    FROM objects AS o
    JOIN attributes AS a 
        ON o.id = a.object_id
), owner_att AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT OWNER_ID, ATTRIBUTE
    FROM obj_att
), dist_owners AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT OWNER_ID
    FROM objects
), owner_pairs AS (
    SELECT a.owner_id as a_id, b.owner_id as b_id
    FROM dist_owners AS a
    JOIN dist_owners AS b
        ON a.owner_id <> b.owner_id
), object_mixed_attributes AS (
    SELECT op.*, oba.*, owa.attribute as b_att
    FROM owner_pairs AS op
    JOIN obj_att AS oba ON oba.owner_id = op.a_id
    LEFT JOIN owner_att AS owa ON owa.owner_id = op.b_id and oba.attribute = owa.attribute
)
SELECT op.a_id as owner_a
    ,op.b_id as owner_b 
    ,count(distinct(om_a.id)) as count_a
    ,count(distinct(om_b.id)) as count_b
    ,count(distinct(iff(om_a.b_att is not null,om_a.id,null))) as similarity_a_to_b
    ,count(distinct(iff(om_b.b_att is not null,om_b.id,null))) as similarity_b_to_a
    ,count_a-similarity_a_to_b as unique_a
    ,count_b-similarity_b_to_a as unique_b        
FROM owner_pairs AS op
JOIN object_mixed_attributes AS om_a ON om_a.a_id = op.a_id
JOIN object_mixed_attributes AS om_b ON om_b.a_id = op.b_id
WHERE op.a_id < op.b_id
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

which gives:

```
OWNER_A OWNER_B COUNT_A COUNT_B SIMILARITY_A_TO_B   SIMILARITY_B_TO_A   UNIQUE_A    UNIQUE_B
5000    6000    3       3       2                   1                   1             2
```

Given it's all equijoin's you will get the best performance out merge joins. looking at the profiles for this tiny example there are a couple `WithReference` blocks which over large tables, can sometime be slow than just reading from the table twice, this comes form the CTE being reused. So playing there can help.

Also I have ben lazy and not fully expanded the selects, thus using x.* at time, and maybe those values are not needed lower down. The complier will solve that for us, and if your tables are that large, then it will be lost in the wash.